# PHPunit Global Variable returns NULL

Tags: php, phpunit

I'm new to php Unit test, but I could installed it and make it work (PHP 7.1.2 / phpUnit 6.1.1 on a Mac / MAMP system). But I now I can't let it test my app. Probably due to a strange class architectural hierarchy.

In my autoload.php I load my classes like that:

```
/* get timing functions */
$th = new TimingHelper();

/* Get basic functions */
$basic = new basic();

/* Get App data (param: fake localhost true / false) */
$App = new App(); 

/* Start DB Connection */
$db = new db(0);

/* Get usr data  (param: fake user mode true / false, user id) */
$usr = new User();
```

There are even more classes... ;)

Now inside the User Class I get the previous classes like that:

```
class User {
     /* get DB connection */
    private $db, $App, $tr, $th, $basic;

    public function __construct() {

        /* get DB connection */
        Global $db, $App, $tr, $th, $basic;
        $this->db = $db;
        $this->App = $App;
        $this->tr = $tr;
        $this->th = $th;
        $this->basic = $basic;

        /* Start timing */
        $this->th->start();
    }
}
```

That's probably not way one should do it, but it works ;)

But now if I want to use phpUnit, I heard it ignores global objects, so

```
 var_dump($this->th);
```

is NULL.

Is there no way, that I can use phpUnit with my class system? If not, what do I need to change?

I tried to extend each class, but then my app was SUPER slow...

Comment: You should pass all of your global variables to as constructor arguments - then you won't need global variables any more

Comment: Hi Robbie, yes that could work. But it's also not so nice to have so many arguments then... No other idea?

Comment: Arguably it's nicer than using global variables in OOP. You're already setting all of the global arguments to class properties in your constructor, so why not allow them to be passed to the constructor instead? You could make them nullable if you have cases where you don't always want/need to pass them

Comment: Yes, I see your point. But now I have in my test file this: $usr = new User($db); PhpUnit gives me an error: Undefined variable: db. But I load in the phpunit.xml file my autloader.php, were i defined $db. <phpunit bootstrap="inc/autoload.php"> Why is this not working?

Comment: It works now! I needed to add Global $usr; in the testfile!

Comment: Something else: I now get this error: Error: Class 'NumberFormatter' not found. Its due to an unloaded php extension (php_intl.dll). I tried to add it in phpunit.xml: <ini name="extension" value="ext/php_intl.dll" /> But it does not work.